# Cannot have multiple awaits in the same async function?

Tags: javascript

```
function fakeRequest(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4500) + 500;
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (delay > 4500) {
                resolve(url + ": success")
            }
            else {
                reject(url = ": error")
            }
        }, delay);
    })
  })
}

async function makeTwoRequests() {
    let data1 = await fakeRequest("/page1");
    console.log("Data 1:", data1)
    let data2 = await fakeRequest("/page2");
    console.log("Data 2:", data2)
}
makeTwoRequests()
```

When I remove data1 or data2 and just have 1 await it works. But when there are 2 or more it errors out saying: `Uncaught (in promise) : error`
I don't know what's happening here. Please help me out

Thanks!

Comment: If you await a promise that rejects, it becomes a thrown error. Change the reject inside `fakeRequest` to a resolve and I bet the problem goes away. Your fake request creates this problem by design.

Comment: Also, you really ought to use a keyword to declare the `delay` variable: `let` or `const` or at least `var`.

Comment: And your reject statement uses an `=` instead of a `+`. Almost certainly a typo, but it explains exactly why your error reads ": error".

Comment: Thank you! It did go away, the chance of the delay being greater than 4500ms is very small so it didn't run. Could you please make your comment an answer?

Comment: Okay, I used let. And yea, it was a typo, I corrected that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you await a promise that rejects, it becomes a thrown error.

Change the `reject` inside `fakeRequest` to a resolve and I bet the problem goes away.

This works for me:

```js
function fakeRequest(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4500) + 500;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (delay > 4500) {
        resolve(url + ": success")
      } else {
        resolve(url + ": error")
      }
    }, delay);
  })
}

async function makeTwoRequests() {
  let data1 = await fakeRequest("/page1");
  console.log("Data 1:", data1)
  let data2 = await fakeRequest("/page2");
  console.log("Data 2:", data2)
}

makeTwoRequests()
```

There were a couple other issues with the sample code:

- `delay` ought to be declared with a keyword like `let`, `const`, or `var`; this is necessary to guarantee that each invocation of the function uses its own private version instead of a shared one, and to prevent this function from changing variables in the outer scope
- the `reject` call uses `=` instead of `+`, which redefines and returns the `url` variable instead of concatenating the URL string with the literal `: error` string
- there was an extra closing `})`, which prevented this code from parsing

---

But I think I get what you're up to: you're trying to simulate a situation in which API calls usually succeed, except for some that fail by timing out.

Your `fakeRequest` *does* accomplish that, but your calling code isn't capable of handling the problem. For that, you'd need something like this:

```js
async function makeTwoRequests() {
  let data1
  try {
    data1 = await fakeRequest("/page1");
  } catch ( error ) {
    console.error(`request 1 threw`, error)
    // here, you might return, or re-throw, or fall through
  }
  
  let data2
  try {
    data2 = await fakeRequest("/page2");
  } catch ( error ) {
    console.error(`request 2 threw`, error)
    // here, you might return, or re-throw, or fall through
  }
}
```